# iphone:Display data in detail view according to the cell selected in mainview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am JSON parsing to fetch data for my tableviews.I succeed in displaying the data if statically specified.In my mainview,it shows a list of categories.When I select a cell,I need to display the subcategories by passing the categoryid from mainview.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [mmenuitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *selectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected %@",[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];
```

With this code I got the categoryID correctly in **selectID**.

I need to pass this ID to subCatView,where the data is collected from 
**URL:http://mysite.in/getJson.php?method=showMenu&res_id=1&cat=**

I need to place the catID from mainView into the cat in above URL.

**How could I change the didSelectRowAtIndexPath in mainView and viewDidLoad in subCatView?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is :-
1.)First create a NSString  object in subCatView controller.
2.)After that when you are passing to the subCatView set your category value in NSString object.
3.)Access that value in the subCatView controller viewDidLoad or other method where you want.

Some code that will give you the glimpse of what you have to do:-
 In subCategoryViewController .h file do:-

```
NSString *categorystring;
```

Make property and synthesize it.

In Main view controller do:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    subCategoryViewController *subCatView=[[[subCategoryViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"subCategoryViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    NSDictionary *dict = [mmenuitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *selectID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected %@",[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];

    [subCatView setCategorystring:cell.textLabel.text];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:subCatView animated:YES];
}
```

NOW Access this string in subCategoryViewController file.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.But in subCatView,I got self.categoryString as null